# Build a new hash by iterating over a hash. Most elegant way?

Tags: ruby, hash

There has to be a more elegant way than this right?

```
rates = { 40 => 2.75, 25 => 3.25, 15 => 4.75 }

effective_rates = {}
rates.each do |depos, rate|
  effective_rates[depos] = rate/1200
end
```

Comment: Hopefully this is just a made up example because I wouldn't suggest using float for precise calculations.  You would get a lot of rounding errors.

Comment: err... yes... Seriously though, good point. I guess it's time to break out the BigDecimals.

Comment: Although, as a trivia note, the fractions (.25 and .75) used in the example happen to be two of the very few that *are* represented exactly in floating point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
effective_rates = rates.merge(rates){|depos, rate| rate/1200}
```

Comment: Wow, merging the hash with itself. Interesting.

Comment: This is my favourite. Very nice indeed.

Answer (score 4):

Right.

```
rates = { 40 => 2.75, 25 => 3.25, 15 => 4.75 }
effective_rates = Hash[rates.map{|depos, rate| [depos, rate/1200]}]
# => {40=>0.0022916666666666667, 25=>0.0027083333333333334, 15=>0.003958333333333334}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
effective_rates = rates.inject({}) { |m, (k,v)| m[k] = v/1200; m }
```

Comment: That is cool.  I didn't know you could make a list of the second argument of the block like that.  That cleans up a lot of code for me where I used to use v[0] and v[1].

Comment: The *destructuring assignment* or, perhaps, *destructing bind* is definitely useful. Ruby has all the best features from the other languages. :-)  Ruby's general multiple assignment `(a, b, c = d, e, f)` has a lot of useful variations.

Comment: This is just standard destructuring bind. It works everywhere a normal bind works: on the left side of an assignment expression, in block parameter declarations (as in this case) and in method parameter declarations.